# Exchange 2010 migration

Tags: exchange-2010, migration

I want to migrate accounts from a hosted service to an Exchange 2010 Server. It is IMAP to MAPI, so I wonder if there is a fast way to do this. I know that exchange 2007 had a special role for this so I hope there is a similar way in exchange 2010. 
I want to migrate around 50 accounts

Answer (score 3):

I am unclear what you mean by " I know that exchange 2007 had a special role for this". There is no IMAP to Exchange copying functionality in Exchange 2007. There is the [Microsoft Transporter Suite](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1329) (which isn't actually a part of Exchange 2007) and Microsoft [confirms that they aren't updating it for Exchange 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee681554.aspx).

If I were in your shoes I'd look at using [imapcopy](http://code.google.com/p/imapcopy/) (or your favorite IMAP to IMAP copy utility-- there are a number out there) to copy data from the IMAP accounts into the new Exchange mailboxes.

Comment: thanks for the answer but imapcopy is only for linux or is there a way to make it work with windows? i want to copy from a webhotel to an exchange server

Comment: You don't need to run imapcopy on the destination server, you just need to "point" it at the destination. You could use a throwaway Linux VM to host the imapcopy program and specify the E2K10 server as the destination. There are other IMAP copier tools out there, too, some of which do run on Windows if you have an aversion to Linux.